# Pi 3B gets 0xc000014c error on boot when using updated Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-iot-core

I'm getting a 0xc000014c error when booting the latest version of Windows 10 IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

With the older IoT Core version (16299.15) I was able to use Windows without issues until Windows Update performed an update which resulted in a reboot to the 0xc000014c error. Restoring a backed-up image of the drive and preventing Windows Update from connecting was necessary to keep it running.

Recently IoT Core 17134.1 came out and I've tried using that directly but it just shows the 0xc000014c error immediately without a first boot. What can I look into to resolve this?

I'm using the latest version of Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard to flash the microSD card. I've also tried using the custom option and flashing the .ffu file with this but the result is the same.

I have formatted the Kingston 16GB Class 10 microSD card using [SD Memory Card Formatter 5.0](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/).

This is what the error looks like:

```
Windows Boot Manager

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the
cause. To fix the problem:

    1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
    2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
    3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance.

    Status: 0xc000014c
    Info: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by purchasing a microSD card that is officially supported by Microsoft ([of which there is only two](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist#storage-media)).

Comment: hmmm no it is not, i'm using the officially supported Sandisk Ultra 16GB micro SDHC and i'm receiving the same error :( i'll try to use the above mentioned formatting tool to see if it fix the thing

Comment: no, even with the above mentioned format tool nor the native one or DIskPart (also using the most profound disk clean option) it didn't work again. maybe the memoty card is F**d up, but it works great if i install raspbian for example...

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted answer... It kept other people who may have an actual solution from posting their answers... Now I'll have to keep searching the web, which is hard as f**k because it keeps finding PC results, not IoT....

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Samsung 32GB micro SD card, and using Windows 10 Ver. 10.0.17763.107.
(Which is currently the latest)

I got this error after shutting my Raspberry Pi down by disconnecting power supply.
I was working on deploying apps via local internet from VS2019.

I was able to overcome this by simply waiting ~30seconds. (But I don't think it was longer than a minute)
Afterwards I was surprised by seeing Windows image, followed by the loading circle of dots.